# How to use openssl to verify a certificate just like a browser?

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate

I am using openssl to verify certificates but it seems that at lean in one case, it will fail to verify a certificate even if the browsers to consider the certificate valid.

```
openssl s_client -connect test.uk.example.com:443
+ sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p'
depth=0 /C=GB/ST=CB/L=Cambridge/O=acme Systems Inc./OU=Development Operations acme/CN=acme.com/CN=*.acme.com/CN=*.uk.acme.com/CN=*.acme.com/CN=*.vmd.acme.com/CN=*.acme.net/CN=*.eng.acme.net
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 /C=GB/ST=CB/L=Cambridge/O=acme Systems Inc./OU=Development Operations acme/CN=acme.com/CN=*.acme.com/CN=*.uk.acme.com/CN=*.acme.com/CN=*.vmd.acme.com/CN=*.acme.net/CN=*.eng.acme.net
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=0 /C=GB/ST=CB/L=Cambridge/O=acme Systems Inc./OU=Development Operations acme/CN=acme.com/CN=*.acme.com/CN=*.uk.acme.com/CN=*.acme.com/CN=*.vmd.acme.com/CN=*.acme.net/CN=*.eng.acme.net
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
```

The same certificate is properly validated by the browsers.

How should I call oepnssl in order to be sure that the validation passes?

Answer (score 3):

The most likely cause is that OpenSSL hasn't been configured with or can't find a list of trust anchors to use for verifying the certificate path.

You can pass them explicitly with `-CApath` or `-CAfile`.

Comment: You are right, still can you provide a scriptable solution for installing these certificates?

Comment: If your OS doesn't come with a pre-defined list, one way is to use the Curl script that pulls the list from Firefox: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Comment: I tried `openssl s_client  -connect $REMHOST:$REMPORT -CAfile cacert.pem` but I get the same error. (cacert.pem is the file got from the link you posted)

Comment: It's hard to know from your question whether the DN you're posting is a dummy one. You might be using a cert issued from your own internal CA. There's clearly a non-standard use of CNs in your example anyway. You can also check the full server config using [this SSL checker](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/).

Comment: @sorin For most platforms you could also try the `certs` subdirectory of the path returned by `openssl version -d`. That is, give option `-CApath $(openssl version -d | awk -F'"'  '{ print $2 }')/certs` to your `openssl s_client` command. Cygwin and Ubuntu at least have  a workable set of public CA certificates there. I recall these are not provided by OpenSSL itself any more, so these CA certificates are provided as symbolic links to the platform provided certificate repository.